# Convert cm to mm using Regex.Replace()

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to take the following input `<tag>30.234234cm</tag>` and get the following output `<tag>302.34234mm</tag>`. Where the value between the tags is a value in centimetres that may be decimal or integer, and the goal is to convert that value to millimetres.

```
var input = "<tag>30.234234cm</tag>";
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d+(\.\d+)?)cm", (double.Parse("$1") * 10).ToString() + 
    "mm", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I am using the expression `(\d+(\.\d+)?)` for the first capture group. However, `$1` will not work in the context of `double.Parse($1)`. How can I get the value of the unit, convert it and replace it in the example string provided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well,

```
  double.Parse("$1")
```

tries to parse `"$1"` constant `string` and fails. I suggest using *lambda*:

```
  var input = "<tag>30.234234cm</tag>";

  input = Regex.Replace(
      input, 
     @"(\d+(\.\d+)?)cm", 
      match => (double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) * 10).ToString() + "mm",
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Here `match.Groups[1].Value` is a value of the captured group (`30.234234` in the example)

Comment: Note this is using the `Regex.Replace` overload that takes a `System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator` as the third arg, in case that's not clear.

Comment: Thank you, this worked with no problems. You're right about `"$1"` being passed as a constant. The lambda is quite elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `"(\d+(\.\d+)?)cm"` with "cm" as a capture, because of that you can't perform `double.Parse("$1")

Comment: I don't think `cm` is the reason it can't be parsed. It's that `$1` itself cannot be parsed.

Comment: Omitting the unit "cm" from the string will still throw an exception.